# how do i compile and run simple java files on eclipse from a src folder?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am in an intro cs course learning Java and the prof gives us unfinished files to complete for our projects. The last projects have been simple and Ive been able to just open eclipse, start a new project, and create a new class with a the same name and just copy and paste the plain text from the files he gives us. However this time that approach isnt working. Basically I have the folder called "src" and i need to know exactly how I can open it in eclipse and start working on the project and be able to run it. Please help me.

basically i downloaded "Project3" from my prof's website. I unzipped it and it conatined project3.pdf - the project outline, and the folder named "src"
inside the src folder are Project3.java and sample3.java that are both used together in the project. All i need to know how to do is to be able to open them in eclipse and start working on it. If i copy and paste the plain text fro the java files to a new project in eclipse i get all kinds of errors.

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/eclipse/  You need to create a new project, and copy the source file into it.

Comment: It would probably be easier, and much quicker, to just ask a classmate, or the professor to walk you through the steps.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you can just copy-paste the files into eclipse.

Second, you can use `File -> Import -> General -> File System` to import files from the file system into eclipse after creating a new Java project.